# what is the second hex number returned while examining a pointer with gdb?

Tags: c, linux, pointers, assembly, gdb

I'm currently trying to learn low level programming from a book called "the art of exploitation".
The book, after writing some code, examines it with gdb. I'm now in the section about pointers.

The code i'm on now is this:

```
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char str_a[20]; //20 charachters array
    char *pointer;
    char *pointer2;

    strcpy(str_a, "hello world\n");
    pointer = str_a; //set pointer to the start of the array
    printf("%s\n", pointer);

    pointer2 = pointer + 2; 
    printf(pointer2);
    strcpy(pointer2, "y you guys\n");
    printf("%s\n", pointer);
    ...
```

In gdb i put a break on the line `printf("%s\n", pointer);`.

Then I examine the pointer `*pointer` using the command `x/xw pointer`, and it returns `0x7fffffffde20: 0x6c6c6568`. I understant that `0x7fffffffde20` is the memory the pointer is pointing to, but I don't understand what `0x6c6c6568` is.

Then I use `x/xw &pointer` to see directly the memory `*pointer` is located, and this time it returns `0x7fffffffde10:  0xffffde20`. I keep not understanding what the second hex is.

If I try to examine it with the command `x/xw 0xffffde20` it returns

> `0xffffde20:   Cannot access memory at address 0xffffde20`

Can somebody help me?

Comment: It seems that your addresses are longer than 32 bits and if you only read 32 bits and try to use it as an address to read from, it fails. I assume, `x/xw` doesn't show enough content to be used as an address.

Comment: The book probably shows examples from a system with 32bits integers and pointers. Your system is probably different. You need to adjust commands to read from memory accordingly.

Comment: You should use `x/xa` to display addresses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Then I examine the pointer *pointer using the command `x/xw pointer`, and it returns
>
> `0x7fffffffde20: 0x6c6c6568`.
>
> I understant that `0x7fffffffde20` is the memory the `pointer` is pointing to, but I don't understand what `0x6c6c6568` is.

The debugger simply shows you an address and the content stored at that address.

In your code `pointer` points to your array where you copied the string `"hello world\n"`
In memory this is (hexadecimal)
`68 65 6C 6C 6F 20 77 6F 72 6C 64 0A`

When you read as a 32 bit integer (via `x/xw`) the first 4 bytes are interpreted as an integer. Assuming your machine uses little endian memory order, this is taken as the value `0x6c6c6586`.
If you read again at the next address, you will get the integer representation of `"o wo"` and `"rld\n"`.

> Then I use `x/xw &pointer` to see directly the memory `*pointer` is located, and this time it returns
>
> `0x7fffffffde10:  0xffffde20`
>
> I keep not understanding what the second hex is.

Again, you get an address and some content. The type/size of the content is defined by the command you use to read it. You read 32 bits and you get 32 bits from that address.

What result are we to expect here?

In previous command you read memory at the address where `pointer` points to.
This time you read memory at the address where `pointer` itself is located.

Remember:
The first command showed address `0x7fffffffde20`.
What you see now it that `pointer` variable is stored at `0x7fffffffde10` and the first 32bits are `0xffffde20`. Notice that this is the similar to the value that was seen as address in first read command.

This means, `0xffffde20` is just the half of `0x7fffffffde20` with the other half missing. You simply did not read enough to show them.

As @jester mentioned in comment, you should use `x/xa` to display addresses.

> If I try to examine it with the command `x/xw 0xffffde20` it returns
>
> `0xffffde20:   Cannot access memory at address 0xffffde20`

With the finding above this is no surprise. You provided only part of the address and this results in an invalid memory access.

From the numbers your memory layout and content is similar to this:

```
0x7fffffffde30 still str_a         xx xx xx xx
0x7fffffffde28 still str_a         72 6C 64 0A 00 xx xx xx
0x7fffffffde20 char str_a[20]      68 65 6C 6C 6F 20 77 6F 
0x7fffffffde18 ...
0x7fffffffde10 char *pointer       0x7fffffffde20  == address of str_a
0x7fffffffde08 char *pointer2
```

Answer (score 1):

The second number is the contents of the item it is pointing to.  In this case

```
6c6c6568
= lleh
= hell backwards
= the first 4 characters of hello
```

I don't know the answer to the second question.